# How to predict future sequence data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently doing a signal processing project. However, this is very different to projects I did before and I am struggling to find a good start point to do this.

My problem is as follows.

I have signals recorded from machines in every minute for 6 hours. i.e. the length of the signal of a machine is 6*60 = `360`. They have recorded these signals for each machine for a month. In other words, each machine has 360 length signals for `28` days. I have the data of about `2000` machines in my dataset.

If you want to get the idea of how my dataset looks like, I have mentioned a quick overview of it below (Note: each signal in each day is 360 length long as described in the question).

```
machine_num, day1, day2, ..., day28
m1, [12, 10, 5, 6, ...], [78, 85, 32, 12, ...], ..., [12, 12, 12, 12, ...]
m2, [2, 0, 5, 6, ...], [8, 5, 32, 12, ...], ..., [1, 1, 12, 12, ...]
...
m2000, [1, 1, 5, 6, ...], [79, 86, 3, 1, ...], ..., [1, 1, 12, 12, ...]
```

My client expects a model that predicts the signal sequence of each machine for next 3 days. i.e. in day29, day30, day31. In other words, the model should learn the sequences from day1 to day29 and predict the next three sequences.

So, I understand that I have to do the prediction based on the patterns of each machine from day1 to day29. I also understand that this is something to do with deep learning.

However, in my previous projects I have only used deep learning for simple classification problems. Since, the client expects a sequence (where length = 360), I am wondering what are the deep learning models that I should use and how to do the prediction.

Note: my preferred programming language is python

Note: I am not limited to deep learning and happy to explore answers using other techniques as well.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: There are many traditional time series models to consider, as well as machine learning oriented approaches that don't involve deep models. Is there a particular reason you think deep learning is necessary, or especially well suited for this problem?

Comment: @user20160 Thank you for the comment. I am not limited to deep learning and happy explore other solutions as well. Please let me know if you have any suggestions :)

Comment: This question falls in the domain of [tag:time-series], which is very large. Some neural-network oriented methods include [tag:lstm] [tag:gru] [tag:rnn].